# Merging in multiple XML sources in XSLT by calling java methods

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I know it's possible to create java objects and call methods from XSLT.  If the method I'm calling returns a DOM document is it possible to merge that into the XML document being processed?

Comment: Using Xalan, or something else?  And when you say "merge into the XML document being processed" you mean you then want to apply-templates to it right (as opposed to just copy it into the output)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way external calls from XSLT to Java behave depends entirely on the XSLT processor you are using - it's not defined in the standard. I would expect the answer is yes - the DOM document will be made visible as a node and can be processed like any other node (for exmaple, it can be copied to the result tree using xsl:copy-of) - but you can only ask the question in relation to a specific XSLT processor.